# javascript setinterval using if condition showing images

Tags: javascript

I need to show three images one by one with using javascript setinterval function can you please any one help me.

Bellow is my html code.

```
<div class="imageHolder">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" style="display:none;" class="image1" border="0" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" style="display:none;" class="image2" border="0" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="display:none;" class="image3" border="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show you effort also. If you want help, help yourself first.

Comment: Least you could do is to post pseudo code correctly.

Comment: var img1 = document.getElementById('image1');
var img1 = document.getElementById('image2');
var img1 = document.getElementById('image3');



setInterval(function(){ 
 nFilter.style.display='block',
 3000
);


setInterval(function(){ 
 nFilter.style.display='block',
 6000
);


setInterval(function(){ 
 nFilter.style.display='block',
 9000
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function start() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.imageHolder img');
    var images_count = images.length;
    var image_index = false;
    var delay = 3000; // 3 seconds delay

    function animateImageHolder() {
      if (false !== image_index) {
        images[image_index].style = 'display:none';
        image_index++;
        image_index = (image_index < images_count ? image_index : 0);
      } else {
        image_index = 0;
      }
      images[image_index].style = 'display:inline';
    }

    animateImageHolder();
    setInterval(animateImageHolder, delay);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: You put `// 3 seconds delay` but it's one second.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty much like "do my job for me" but you are honest in your english.
You did not say how long each image should be visible so I set it to 3 seconds (`interval = 3000`).
I recommend you to set the style attribute of the first image to be `style="display:block"` and the rest to `style="display:none"`.

```
function slider(element) {
    var next_image = 0
      , interval = 3000
      , images = Array.prototype.filter.call(element.children, function(child) {
            return child.tagName === "IMG";
        })
    ;
    setInterval(function() {
        images.forEach(function(image, i) {
            image.style.display = i === next_image ? "block" : "none";
        })
        next_image = (next_image + 1) % images.length;
    }, interval);
}

slider(document.querySelector("div.imageHolder"))
```